# Is there way to skip minute part out of time if it's zero while formatting DateTime?

Tags: .net, datetime, formatting

Here's what I need: `15h37`, but `15h` instead of `15h00` (`H'h'mm`) or `15h0`(`H'h'm`).
It looks like there is no way to achieve this with just formatting engine itself, is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format hours and minutes separately, and use separate formatting for positive-negative-zero values, like this:

```
static string FormatTime(DateTime dt) {
    return string.Format("{0}h{1:##m;;}", dt.Hour, dt.Minute);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/mqkUGd)

Comment: Well, that does the trick, but that's exactly what I'd love to avoid.

Comment: @AndriyK Unfortunately, .NET designers didn't think of `m` as a number, forcing us to resort to some ugly tricks, such as this one. At least this way you don't have to replace `"00m"` with regex in an additional step after formatting. On the other hand, you can build your own `HoursMinutes` object, make it `IFormattable`, and provide your custom formatting logic there. Adding an extension method to `DateTime` that produces an `HourMinute` object simplifies the way you call the formatter. Unfortunately, you have to do it outside the format string. Дуже прикро, але нажаль, це так :-)

Comment: In fact, I don't need that trailing m, so way clearer `{1:##}` is sufficient for my case. And yes, I just ended up implementing my own `HoursMinutes` class. Дякую, anyway!

Comment: You'll might want to use `{1:00}` instead of `{1:##}` if you want to coerce nonzero minutes to a two-digit format, e.g. `15h01` instead of `15h1`.

Comment: Right, but this way zeroes will be there if it's 0 minutes, and that's exactly the problem I was trying to solve. I ended up with something in between: `{1:00;;''}`.